# Static file location and cache control headers

Tags: cloudbees

When using the basic Tomcat container in Cloudbees, are the static files served by Tomcat or Apache?  I need to set the header so browsers do not cache a certain file which would be done in the Apache .htaccess file or I could write a servlet filter for Tomcat to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Cloudbees don't use Apache frontend but nginx. All requests, including static resources, are served by the application container (tomcat, jboss). A best practice is to distribute them on a CDN for better performances and low latency for application users, see http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Using+a+CDN

Answer (score 0):

In my experience all requests arrive at the Tomcat level.
Here is an exempt from my service logs at cloudbees:

11:10:53.031 [http-8841-2] DEBUG o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'spring' processing GET request for [/resources/images/logo.png]

Obviously the request for the logo.png file got there.

By the way, I think they use ngineX not Apache.